# Detect ID of a textbox when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When there are many dynamically created text boxes, is there way to detect the ID of the textbox when a user clicks on any of those text boxes?

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textCount = 0;
    var textfieldWrapper = $("#textfieldWrapper");
    var x = textfieldWrapper.length; 
    var textfield = $("#namebutton");

    $(textfield).click(function() {
        textCount++;
        $(textfieldWrapper).append('<div>' + '<div class="name" id="textfield_0' + textCount + '">' + '<input type="text" id="field_' + textCount + '" placeholder="dynamic box"/>');
        x++;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Yes, we can get the id of dynamically created text boxes. For this you have to set the id of Text boxes. so you have to show the code first. hou you are creating the text boxes..

Comment: @Nelie Don't worry dude, you have got my upvote! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
<input onclick="alert(this.id)" />
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: i assume you are trying to do something with the id. to make things simpler i suggest you use the data attribute. <input data-id="id"> can be retrieved as $(this).data("id"). its cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that by applying a class to those textboxes and using (THIS), i.e. current object. Please check the code below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".classOfTextbox", function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(id);
        });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `alert(this.id);` is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in *vanilla JavaScript*

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement ||
        ((e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) && (e.target.getAttribute('type') === "text"))
    ) {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('id'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class = "click" id = "1">Item 1</a>
<a class = "click" id = "2">Item 2</a>

$(".click").click(function(){
    pos = this.attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#textBox).on(click, function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'););
});
```

if you are going through multiple textboxes:

```
$(.textboxes).each( function() {   
    $(this).on(click, function() {
       alert($(this).attr('id'););
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function or use jquery click event 
1) using javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="data" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script>
```

2)using jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="data">

$(document).on('click','input[type="text"]',function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textfieldWrapper').on('click', 'input', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8wL8jhe/).